# How to determine which apps are incompatible with an iOS upgrade?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, software-update, upgrade

Since apps sometimes stopped working after an iOS upgrade in the past, I’m curious as how to know in advance which apps will be affected (I don’t wanna use any trial-and-error approach).

This particular case is about upgrading iOS 14.8.1 to 15.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a technical way to check that before actually performing the upgrade.

The only other way is reading, so for every app that is important for you you can do:

1. Check the app store when the last update has been published. If an update has been released e.g. after iOS 15.0 (Sept 2021) and/or iOS 15.4 (March 2022) has been released that the chance is good that this update includes compatibility fixes with the iOS version that was released before.
2. Check the reviews in app store, especially those with a lower rating. Often people write what is going wrong in the reviews.
3. Check the web site of the app developer/company if there is a forum where app users discuss about the app and potential problems that occur on recent iOS versions.

Comment: Thank you! It’s just not feasible doing this for hundreds of apps for each upgrade :/ Don’t get it why Apple still doesn’t provide this info (and asks for confirmation) before any upgrade takes place. They definitely should do.